# Click not working from the appended external content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Created two simple html files test.html and frame.html and here I am loading  frame.html inside the test.html. But calling functions of frame.html in the test.html is not working, its giving function not defined

`test.html`

```html
<html>
  <head>   
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 align="center">TEST AB TEST</h3>
    <div id="load_frame" ></div>
    <div style='padding:30px;background-color:red; '>
      <input id="test_Button" type='button' value='test_Button'/>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#load_frame').append('<object data="frame.html"/>');
      });
      $("#test_Button").bind( "click",function(){
        console.log('aaaaaaaa');
        myFunction1();
      });
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

`frame.html`

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 align="center">TEST Frame</h3>
    <div style='padding:30px;width:500px;'>
      <input id="frame_button" type='button' value='frame_button'/>
    </div>
    <script>
      function myFunction1() {
        alert('Inside frame');
      }
      $("#frame_button").bind( "click",function(){
        myFunction1();
        console.log('aaaaaaaa');
      });
            
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`Error`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction1 is not defined

Comment: u append the content on document ready - so after the DOM is loaded and try to access functions inside the DOM which is not there yet.

This might work: `$('body').on('click','#frame_button', function(){...});`

Comment: No success, Its not going inside the click block only

Comment: You expect a function to be found inside an object tag? Those functions do not show up in the global scope of the parent. If it did, we would have a lot of problems on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function in the context of the frame window

```
 $("#test_Button").bind( "click",function(){
    //reference to the frame window
    var frameWindow =$('#load_frame object')[0].contentWindow;
    // the function is a property of that window
    frameWindow.myFunction1();
 });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3rcZcDQtmhK76PlivHLo?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: its  working fine in demo, but in my local its giving error as Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: @Abhi right. You can not do it in a cross origin situation due to *"same origin policy"* unless you control the source for both pages

Comment: Are you working off the file protocol? AKA you are not running a server? Or are you working with two different domains or ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply access the content of an other frame. This fact is implementet by browser vendors for security reasons.

If you really want to "talk" between frames you can use `postMessage` for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I can fetch the contents of other html file. But I am not able to call the functions of appended frame

Comment: If you want to execute an js function in an frame in the page you have to use postMessages as i stated